# Getting the button id that leads to a new activity - android

Tags: android

I have 5 `Buttons` and every `Button` has an id (I used `setId()` to give each `Button` a unique id). All the `Buttons` open the same `Activity` with an `Intent`. Is there any way I can pass the id of the `Button` which was clicked to the new `Activity`?

Comment: Use Intent.putextra() to pass the value from the old activity to the new one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just add the id to the `Intent` as an extra? Like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("button_id", button.getId());
startActivity(intent);
```

You can then retrieve the id in the new `Activity` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int buttonId = intent.getIntExtra("button_id", 0);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just put the needed data to the intent:

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(...);
            intent.putExtra("id", v.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
button2.setOnClickListener(listener);
button3.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

And later you can get this data from the intent at the new activity.